# Font special ASCII characters in 2.6

Tags: text-object

To display a special font character (a character that does not have it's own key on the keyboard) in most Windows apps you press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key then enter an ASCII character number using the numeric keypad (located on the right side of the keyboard).

This technique does not seem to work in Blender text edit mode.

Any solutions?

Comment: Where do you want to enter it? *Text Editor*, *Text* object in 3D View, *Python Console*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enter special characters for a Text object,

- enter editmode
- type any letter
- go to *Redo panel* (it should show *Insert Text*)
- open *Notepad* or another text editor
- enter your special char using Alt key
- copy and paste the char to the *Text* property field in Blender's *Redo panel*

[image: Text Object - Insert special char via Redo panel]

Another way is to

- load an external text file with the *Text Editor*,
- then click the menu *Edit > Text To 3D Object > One Object*.

[image: Text to 3D Object]

Comment: @Cymatical If this answer answered your question, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark button below the voting buttons above.

Comment: where is the redo panel on blender 2.8? I can't find the "insert text" option

Comment: Also the second option doesn't work. The special character doesn't make it to the text.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users, here is another variation on the first method detailed by CoDEmanX. Use the first three steps of his first method, but instead of opening Notepad, in the search bar of the Start menu, type "character map", which will point to the character map utility included with Windows. Open the character map, in which you can select the character(s) you want to use in Blender, and from the "Characters to copy" bar in Character map utility, copy the characters into the Text property field as CoDEmanX described.

A preliminary test suggests that this might also be a way to get an extended ascii symbol into other text items, like object names, although it's not clear that this might not run afoul of other error checking.

Finally, I expect that MACos and Linux have similar character map facilities that can be used similarly to that in Windows, but I have no specific knowledge of those platforms.