# How to add special characters as text to Blender

Tags: text-object

I would like to type special characters like stars as text to my blender project ★.

However, I am unable to copy symbols and paste them into blender like I can with normal text.

[image]

What steps do I need to take to be able to type special symbols?

Comment: i guess you need to create a second text

Comment: could you please elaborate on that? do you mean create a second text object?

Comment: yes, that's it, if the common keyboard shortcut doesn't work to create the symbol, i don't see another solution

Comment: Hmm.. There supposedly was a solution many years ago found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10918/font-special-ascii-characters-in-2-6 But I can't for the life of me figure out how to open that 'insert text' window. Would you know by any chance?

Comment: That was in the 2.6 version of Blender but that option seems to have been removed. As @moonboots says, create a second text object and change the Font under Text Properties > Font > Regular to Windings Regular (under Windows). Then you can add any character in that font but you may have to do it by selecting and copying it in Windows Character Map then Edit your font object in Blender and Ctrl-V to Paste it.